# reactjs blank screen while running the code

Tags: reactjs

The code I am working currently below, it's a simple hello world code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- The core React library -->
    <script src="http://localhost/react/react.js"></script>
    <!-- The ReactDOM Library -->
    <script src="http://localhost/react/react-dom.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script type="text/jsx">
        var NewComponent = React.createClass({
            render : function(){
                return (
                    <h2>My Name is React</h2>
                );
            }

        });
        React.render(<NewComponent/>,document.getElementById('content'));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the code am getting a blank screen, there is no error in console.

Comment: It's `ReactDom.render` not `React.render`

Comment: still not getting after using ReactDom.render

Comment: how u r using localhost for react lib ?? use 
`<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>`  for react and react dom reference.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using localhost references, use these references, it will work:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
```

Check this Hello World example: https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/

Answer (score 0):

Make two changes in your code

**First:** After `react v0.13 React.render` is deprecated and so you need to use ReactDOM.render

**Second:** When you specify the script sources, they need should be given relative the index.html file which contains your code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- The core React library -->
    <script src="./relative/path/to/react/react.js"></script>
    <!-- The ReactDOM Library -->
    <script src="./relative/path/to/react/react-dom.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script type="text/jsx">
        var NewComponent = React.createClass({
            render : function(){
                return (
                    <h2>My Name is React</h2>
                );
            }

        });
        ReactDOM.render(<NewComponent/>,document.getElementById('content'));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```